# What is the proper way of naming slim files using numbers for a Sinatra project?

Tags: ruby, sinatra, slim-lang

In my Sinatra app, I am getting an error

```
syntax error, unexpected tINTEGER, expecting tSTRING_CONTENT or tSTRING_DBEG or tSTRING_DVAR or tSTRING_END
```

when I try to name my files something like **1.slim** but not getting the error when I do something like this like calling it **page1.slim**

This is how I had my route that gave me an error

### main.rb

```
get '/1' do
  slim :1
end
```

but it works fine when I do something like

```
get '/1' do
  slim :page1
end
```

What's the problem? in Ruby apps can I not name a view starting with a number?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not about view, slim or something else. it's a symbol thing.

```
:1 #syntax error
```

You can do that like

```
:"1"
```

In your case, the route would look like

```
get '/1' do
  slim :"1"
end
```

Comment: ok, now I was able to continue naming things along the lines of **1.slim** and yes the problem was resolved by using structure like `slim :"1"`